# Vibration Intensity

Tags: vibration

I have a Galaxy S2. This morning it sent me an alert saying that I could get an update, so I did. Ever since then the phone isn't the same. It works fine; the only thing that is different is that the lock screen is different and it has a long vibration when I receive a text message. I can't tell the difference between a call or a text message. It used to vibrate only twice but I don't know how to change it back to that. How do I change it back the previous behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go into settings->sounds and change the vibration intensity along with what vibration pattern is used for calls and text messages.

If this doesn't work, there is an app called Custom SMS Tones on the market, download that and you can change your SMS vibration patterns. It just won't work for e-mail.

Hope this helps!